How to find which header has focus in ag-grid
I have used custom headerComponent for all columns. When navigating through the headers using keyboard, is there a way to know which column header has focus?

You can get a focused header element using selector:
document.querySelector('[role="columnheader"]:focus-visible');

or you can get a column object using API:
const colId = document.querySelector('[role="columnheader"]:focus-visible').getAttribute('col-id');
cons focusedColumn = gridApo.getColumn(colId);


You can get a focused header element.If col-id is not used in other attributes.
document.activeElement.getAttribute('col-id')

